# How do you scale an area of a map of an image in HTML?

Tags: html, dictionary, scale, area

In HTML, how can you scale an area of map?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to scale an `area` element is to change its `coords` attribute value. That value is interpreted as containing coordinates in pixels. Although HTML 4 allows percentages to be used there, this has not been implemented in major browsers; they just ignore the `%` sign and interpret the value as pixels.